# Displaying multiple CSV file contents as HTML tables using pagination in PHP

Tags: php, csv, pagination

I have multiple CSV files, each with the same set of row/column titles but each with different values. For example:

```
CSV-1.csv
A,B,C,C,C,X
A,A,A,A,C,X

CSV-2.csv
A,C,C,C,C,X
A,C,A,A,C,X
```

and so on...

I have been able to figure out how to read the files and convert them into HTML pre-formatted tables. However, I have not been able to figure out how to paginate when there are multiple files with data (as shown above) such that I get only a single table at a time with "Next" and "Previous" buttons (to be able to effectively see the changes in the table and data.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance what the files are, then predetermining the line count for each file would let you do the pageination.

Then it'd be a simple matter of scanning through this line count cache to figure out which file to start reading from, and just keep reading lines/files until you reach the per-page line limit.

Otherwise, you option will be to open/read each file upon each request, but only start outputting when you reach the file/line that matches the current "page" offset. For large files with many lines, this'd be a serious waste of cpu time and disk bandwidth.